# How to remove a row from mongoose object in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
model.Gps.find({EmpName:empName}, function(e,o){


            for (var i = 0; i <o.length; i++) {
                if(o[i].TripNo<tripNo)
                {
                    o.remove({_id:o[i]._id}, function(err, result) {
                    if(err) { throw err; }
                    res.end("<p>Product removed</p>");
                   });
                }
            }

        });
```

Schema:

```
var gpsSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
    EmpName: String, 
    TripNo: String,
    Latitude: String, 
    Longitude : String,
    Timestamp: Date
});
```

how to remove rows that coming under if condition. im new to node js, THanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can query only what you need and remove it with `remove`.

```
model.Gps.find({EmpName:empName, TripNo: {"$lt": tripNo}})
.remove(function(err){
        if(err) { throw err; }
        res.end("<p>Products removed</p>");
     });
```

Comment: Try it in mongo console: db.gps.find({EmpName:empName, TripNo: {$lt: tripNo}})

Comment: Its working in mongo console. but its not in node.js. can u help me?

Comment: try with double quotes